# Classic Windows games on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, minesweeper

Who can live without the games supplies with Windows? Countless hours of productivity have been lost to Minesweeper, Solitaire, Chess and the likes.

Sadly, Microsoft did not include desktop versions of these games in Windows 8 (altough you can download revamped Modern UI versions from the Store). Does anyone know how the run the Windows 7 versions of these in Windows 8?

Comment: We can help you with maybe running the Win7 versions, but asking for clones is off-topic.  I'd recommend removing that.

Comment: I've done a bit of research and found that trying to run the Windows 7 versions of these games can be a bit tricky, and requires some iffy-looking tools to get the job done.

Are you specifically looking for the Windows 7 versions or could it be say, XP version?

Comment: Not specifically, but the Windows 7 versions look a bit nicer

Answer (score 2):

You can run the Windows XP versions of the game relatively easily, as long as you have a Windows XP installed on another machine or VM. You can just copy the game `exe` files over from `C:\Windows\System32\`. You can also copy them from the install disk, but the process is a little more complicated. Here is an [article with full instructions](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/minesweeper-restoring-the-classic-windows-games-in-windows-8/).

To get the Windows 7 versions of the game working is even more work, involving modifying the game binaries. I am not a lawyer, and I have not read the Windows 7 and 8 licences in detail, but I am guessing this is technically violating at least the Windows 7 license, although in reality I doubt you'll attract *that* much attention. I found good instructions on [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/) but I won't link directly here.